# Is that possible to check moderation between scale and nominal variable?

Tags: interaction, mediation

I am trying to find out moderation between scale (independent) and nominal (dependent) variable with moderator- education. There are three variables Culture (independent variable), gender (dependent variable) and education (moderator).